# Issue deploying change set in salesforce prod - code coverage issue

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

Being new to salesforce i'm trying to make a prod deployment but it is failing because of code coverage issue.
These are the apex classes that i wrote:

`HttpCallOut.apxc`

```
public with sharing class HttpCallOut {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callService(string endpoint, string method, string body) {
        try {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('callout:API_SERVICES' + endpoint);
            request.setMethod(method);
            request.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
            request.setBody(body);
            
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            
            if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus() + ' ' + response.getBody());
                throw new CustomException('Error calling endpoint ' + endpoint + 'Status Code: ' + response.getStatusCode() + 'Status: ' + response.getStatus()+ 'Response Body: ' + response.getStatus());
            }
            return;
        } catch (CalloutException  calloutException) {
            throw new CustomException('Error in HttpCallOut callService: ', calloutException);
        }
         
    }

}
```

`CustomException.Apxc`

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

}
```

`HandleUpdateOnReturnRefundCase`

```
public with sharing class HandleUpdateOnReturnRefundCase {
    private HttpCallOut httpCallOut = new HttpCallOut();
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void handleUpdateOnReturnRefundCase(List<Id> caseIds) { 
        List<Case> updatedCases = [select id, Decision__c, ZoroCaseIdentifier__c, Type, Description, ReturnOptions__c from Case where Id in :caseIds];
        Case updatedCase = updatedCases.get(0);

        if((updatedCase.Decision__c == 'Approved' && updatedCase.ReturnOptions__c != null) || updatedCase.Decision__c == 'Rejected') {
            httpCallOut.callService(
                '/salesforce-case-updated',
                 'POST',
                 genPayload(updatedCase.id, updatedCase.ZoroCaseIdentifier__c, updatedCase.Type)
            );
         } else {
             throw new CustomException('Cannot update the case, please fill all required fields');
         }
        update updatedCases;
    }
   
    private static String genPayload(Id caseId, String zoroCaseIdentifier, String caseType) {
        CasePayload casePayload = new CasePayload();
        casePayload.caseId = caseId;
        casePayload.caseType = caseType;
        casePayload.zoroCaseIdentifier = zoroCaseIdentifier;
        return JSON.serialize(casePayload);
    }
}
```

`CasePayload.Apxc`

```
public class CasePayload {
    public Id caseId {
      get { return caseId; }
      set { caseId = value; }
   }
    
    public String zoroCaseIdentifier {
      get { return zoroCaseIdentifier; }
      set { zoroCaseIdentifier = value; }
   }
    
   
    public String caseType {
      get { return caseType; }
      set { caseType = value; }
   }
}
```

For above apex classes i have written test cases:

`HandleUpdateOnReturnRefundCaseTest`

```
@isTest
private class HandleUpdateOnReturnRefundCaseTest {
    
    static testMethod void testApprovedReturnRefundCase() {
        Case mockCase = new Case();
        mockCase.Type = 'Request Return';
        insert mockCase;
        
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new HttpCalloutSuccessTest());
        mockCase.Decision__c = 'Approved';
        mockCase.ReturnOptions__c = 'FOC without Returned Items';
        update mockCase;
        Test.stopTest();
        
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, Decision__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :mockCase.Id];
        for (Case c : cases) {
            system.assertEquals(c.Decision__c, mockCase.Decision__c);
        }
    }
    
    static testMethod void testRejectedReturnRefundCase() {
        Case mockCase = new Case();
        mockCase.Type = 'Request Return';
        insert mockCase;
        
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new HttpCalloutSuccessTest());
        mockCase.Decision__c = 'Rejected';
        update mockCase;
        Test.stopTest();
        
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, Decision__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :mockCase.Id];
        for (Case c : cases) {
            system.assertEquals(c.Decision__c, mockCase.Decision__c);
        }
    }
    
   static testMethod void testCaseApprovedWithoutReturnOptions() {
        try 
        {
          Case mockCase = new Case();
          mockCase.Type = 'Request Return';
          insert mockCase;
            
          Test.startTest();
          Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new HttpCalloutSuccessTest());
          mockCase.Decision__c = 'Approved';
          mockCase.ReturnOptions__c = null;
          update mockCase;
          Test.stopTest();
         } catch (Exception e) {
              System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Please select Return Options before saving'), 'message=' + e.getMessage());
         }  
    }
    
    static testMethod void testCaseUpdatedWithHttpError() {
        try
        {
            Case mockCase = new Case();
            mockCase.Type = 'Request Return';
            insert mockCase;
            Test.startTest();
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new HttpCalloutErrorTest());
            mockCase.Decision__c = 'Approved';
            mockCase.ReturnOptions__c = 'FOC without Returned Items';
        
            update mockCase;
            Test.stopTest();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Error calling endpoint /salesforce-case-updated'), 'message=' + e.getMessage());
        } 
    } 
}
```

`HttpCalloutSuccessTest`

```
global class HttpCalloutSuccessTest implements HttpCalloutMock{
  global HttpResponse respond(HTTPRequest req){
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('{"status":"success"}');
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
  }
}
```

`HttpCalloutErrorTest`

```
@isTest
global class HttpCalloutErrorTest implements HttpCalloutMock{
  global HttpResponse respond(HTTPRequest req){
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setStatusCode(500);
    return res;
  }
}
```

When i run the test in sandbox by clicking "Run ALL Test" - i see that cove coverage is 92%. SO i made outbound set and tried to deploy to prod.

But in prod when i validated inbound change set it complained about code code coverage issue.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong? If test cases are missing then for which part of the code?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So tests passed, no exceptions, "just" code coverage problem? You included the tests in the changeset?

This looks like it's supposed to be called from a Flow/ProcessBuilder (`InvocableMethod`). Did you include that flow in package? Is it active? Or Case trigger (if it's called from trigger)

Or make the unit test call `HandleUpdateOnReturnRefundCase.handleUpdateOnReturnRefundCase()` directly, without "firing mechanism". It's an unit test, not a whole system integration. Test blocks independently and composition separately, will help you nail any errors.

If you still can't figure it out - refresh new sandbox, deploy to it (without unit test run) and continue working there, examine debug logs etc.

Comment: thanks @eyescream, yes i was missing some the flow and its dependency. Thanks for pointing that out. Much appreciated!